# Draw Major Axis and Minor Axis of contour

Tags: matlab, plot, line

[image: Contour]

So I have the above contour and I want to plot a Major Axis and Minor Axis Line of the contour, what I do is exactly like this

```
s=regionprops(image,'Centroid','Orientation','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength');

xMajor=s.Centroid(1) + [-1 1]*(s.MajorAxisLength/2)*cosd(s.Orientation);
yMajor=s.Centroid(2) + [-1 1]*(s.MajorAxisLength/2)*sind(s.Orientation);

xMinor=s.Centroid(1) + [-1 1]*(s.MinorAxisLength/2)*sind(s.Orientation);
yMinor=s.Centroid(2) + [-1 1]*(s.MinorAxisLength/2)*cosd(s.Orientation);

line(xMajor,yMajor);
line(xMinor,yMinor);
```

but what I get so far is the picture below

[image: Result]

am I doing it wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the minor axis, the orientation is `s.Orientation+90`, so `cosd(s.Orientation+90) = sind(s.Orientation)` but `sind(s.Orientation+90) = -cosd(s.Orientation)`.

So you have to use:

```
xMinor=s.Centroid(1) + [-1 1]*(s.MinorAxisLength/2)*sind(s.Orientation);
yMinor=s.Centroid(2) - [-1 1]*(s.MinorAxisLength/2)*cosd(s.Orientation);
```

Comment: but is the output of the 'Orientation' in regionprops is in degree?

Comment: @AbdullahAlMubarok: You are right, this was not the problem, sorry. I have edited my answer.